# SharePoint site online deletion

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, site, delete, script

I mistakenly launched a script that allows the removal of SharePoint online sites and I deleted a very important site. Is there a way to retrieve it?

Comment: raise MS ticket from admin center. They will help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much, if you can show me just how I can proceed to create the ticket, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it deleted permanently, Please open ticket from admin center

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenkumar/2013/07/17/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check `Restore-SPODeletedSite`, [this thread](https://blog.machsol.com/cloud/recover-deleted-site-collections-sharepoint-online) for your reference.

Comment: the problem is that the script I executed permanently delete the site, I did not even in the trash, so I can not run this Cmd